# Unable to Delete Team in D365

Tags: dynamic, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm unable to delete Team in D365, Reassigned record to other User and Removed Team members from Team and Clicked on delete, then Its showing  Error Message as **"The Owner was not provided If you contact support, please provide the technical details."**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhjGq.png)

Comment: That looks like it might be a custom error message. What appears if you click "Show technical details"?

Answer (score 0):

As Aron mentioned in comment, it looks like you have some plugin or custom logic on your action.

From the error it looks like when you reassign the owner it is not yet captured/stored in Database and in addition in your custom logic you are trying to remove team members.

I would suggest, make it two step process, first Change the owner. Once this action is completed (saved in database) then remove the team members. I would also recommend running removing team members logic under system (user), so that system (user) has all the rights to perform action.